# Decoupling capacitors inrush current

Tags: capacitor, filter, decoupling-capacitor, inrush-current

My question relates to decoupling capacitors on power input rails. I see a lot of designs with MCU boards that use only decoupling capacitors and no chokes, beads, inductors, or resistors. Isn't this bad design practice because of the switch-on surges that occur? Are they only using caps because a lot of entry-level MCU applications are relatively low current?

Comment: Our power supplies all soft start, meaning they ramp up over the course of tens of milliseconds.  This reduces the di/dt seen such that the power supplies can handle that current.  We use this approach with distributed loads of several thousands of uF of capacitance.

Answer (score 8):

If the power supply can handle it, then it's no problem. And things like FPGAs and big processors can have peak currents of 100A and power supplies to match and they still don't need inductors.

But blindly adding things like chokes, beads, and inductors introduces inductance that produces resonant peaks with the capacitances and if those peaks land on a noise frequency, the noise will actually be worse than if they weren't there.

It's obvious why it is bad to have resistors in series with a power supply.

Also, soft-starting regulators are a thing which means the inrush is, could potentially, only be on the input capacitor to the whole system since that is the only part of the system that is not behind a regulator which, in theory, could be made to soft-start.

Answer (score 4):

Inductors (as power filters)can have serious cost and space issues, so when you see them on a board or schematic chances are they *have* to be there.

I have only seen inductors used where EMI is a serious issue. Maybe 1 on a video card. On a motherboard you may see many of them, mostly to prevent EMI from local point-of-use regulators from back-feeding into a power supply cable. One could say it also prevents a massive switching supply from sending HF noise into a downstream boost or buck supply which might cause HF harmonics, but keeping supply cables from radiating RF noise is the goal.

In-rush limiters exist as fat PTC resistors. Cold ohms is high, while warm resistance is low, so in rush current into large capacitors or capacitor banks is limited. Often seen on most all SMPS. Resembles a fat MOV but has very low DC resistance.

I have seen resistors as part of power supply RC filters at the power pins of analog IC's, often on a board with digital circuits. They may share common power feeds, so local RC filters (R>=10 ohm, R<=33 ohm) keep an op-amp or comparator supply pins as noise free as possible. Often a low value capacitor (1nF to 100nF) is used with a high value capacitor (10uF to 100uF), especially with wide-band op-amps and fast comparators.

Answer (score 3):

This may more comprehensively answer your question....

For the relatively low value bypass capacitors you're seeing (~10uF or so), the power supply before it will be able to handle the modest energy of the inrush current transient. If there were 1000uF then some type of inrush limiting would more likely be appropriate.

Ferrite beads need to be designed to absorb energy in a particular frequency range of interest; they are more for noise reduction than inrush reduction.

Inductors are also more of a low pass noise filter than for controlling inrush. If an inductor were so large that it would reduce inrush current then it would be so large that it would kill the preceding supply's ability to respond to load transients as well.

Resistors large enough to reduce inrush current would cause too much loss and would also degrade load transient response of the preceding supply as well as add load regulation accuracy degradation.

For a large capacitor bank a thermistor or a MOSFET or other method can be used to limit inrush. You just don't need it for a typical small MCU.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So it's more of a concern with large caps and the power supply draw than it is with components downstream from what I gather.

Comment: My answer wasn't as clear as it could have been. I got partly distracted by other comments in the thread. Ferrite beads and inductors are best suited to filtering particular frequency ranges of noise from passing between upsream and downstream power rails. For small MCUs the smallish bypass cap that is shown is likely to adequately smooth out the voltage ripple on the supply due to current draw from things like turn-on/off edges.

Answer (score 3):

Inrush only happens when you connect a "hot" power supply to a "cold" board. When the power supply is ON the board, it will have to be designed to charge up the caps in controlled fashion (usually by implementing slow start or strict cycle-by-cycle current limiting).

About 20 years ago I worked for a company that designed CompactPCI single-board computers (vertical 6U telco boards). Some are hot-swappable, meaning they can be inserted into a Compact PCI backplane that has active data and power.

A lot of stuff has to happen as a new blade is inserted into the backplane so that the capacitance of the new blade does not pull down the active PCI bus on the backplane. A state machine charges up all capacitance on the backplane VCC while remaining at a safe current limit, then all IO pins are pre-charged to VCC/2 before they are allowed to connect to the master bus. It is very elaborate.

This is 20 years ago. Not sure how much it may have changed since then.

More recently I had to design a motor controller for uh, something. In the 350 Watt range or so. Removable 12S battery pack. That required a pre-charge circuit so that the main bulk capacitance was charged with a controlled current. Otherwise there would be very large sparks upon connection of battery to capacitor. This used a resistor to limit current, and after the cap was charged up, the resistor was bypassed with a FET. The circuit would not be that obvious to you if you looked at it in the layout. You might not realize it was a pre-charge circuit if you didn't have access to the schematic.